# DosBox on CLI Debian 9.6 prints garbage on screen

Tags: linux, debian, dosbox

Today I set up a new virtual machine with Debian 9.6 (i386). I have installed DosBox using apt-get, run it and get
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXXip.png).

I did not know that DosBox can run this way (without X11), and even if it does, then something is broken. There is something wrong with characters, and everything blinks.

Does anybody have an idea what is going on? Do I forgot something to do after installation?